# If I'm using an RTC and ATMega328p (arduino UNO chip), do I need two crystals?

Tags: atmega, crystal, rtc

If I'm using an RTC that requires an external crystal, do I need a second external crystal for my ATMega328p? Or can the two share? What is standard practice for this kind of thing? I'm making a simple wristwatch, and so timing on the ATMega is not so important since the RTC is responsible for keeping track of time.

Hope this was specific enough...thanks!

Comment: Yes the RTC would take a 32.768 kHz crystal. It's DS1337 RTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not. Most AVRs, including the ATmega328P, have an internal 8MHz RC oscillator that, while not perfectly accurate, is certainly good enough for simple operation. Simply configure the fuses to use this internal oscillator instead of an external crystal and you're set.

Another option is to use a RTC that can generate a high-frequency square ware and configure the MCU to use this as an external oscillator. It won't run as quickly as with the internal oscillator, but it may be enough depending on the application.

The RTC, on the other hand, *will* require a crystal. You cannot get around this.